# Why don't we use liquid helium superfluids for infinite clean energy?

Tags: superfluidity

Liquid helium, at a low enough temperature, becomes a superfluid. This would mean that if we stirred it, it would keep spinning forever. Surely this means we could use a small amount of liquid helium to generate infinite energy?

I understand that it would require a lot of energy to make it in the first place, but surely in the long run it would generate more energy than was needed to create the superfluid?

Comment: Why would you expect any more energy output than it took you to get it spinning in the first place?

Comment: In this house... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dc-m9dumEaw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The super fluid in this scenario is technically without friction, and without friction there would be no way to transfer the energy to a turbine without first heating it, defeating the object. It would also lose energy when transferring it to a turbine. The only real use for it would be a *very* efficient method of energy transfer if you had some method of keeping it permanently cold.

Comment: Or energy storage, like a superfluid flywheel.

Answer (score 3):

> This would mean that if we stirred it, it would keep spinning forever.

No.

It would keep spinning forever *if you don't touch it*.

And by "touch" I don't mean mechanically. Bouncing light off it is "touching" it in this context.

If it's moving a generator, it's "touching" something.